# How do I change my output for mode in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, mode

I have created this dataframe which lists all the statistical values

```
     Mean        Median         Mode              Standard Deviation
0   68583.1038   68804.5     ([70850.0], [3])     10656.924306113147 
1   5.9748        6.0        ([6.0], [1924])      1.0379619260839712
2   6.9884        7.0        ([7.0], [1891])      1.0441577658572396
3   3.7412        4.0        ([4.0], [1482])      1.2279342653416256
4   36163.5122   36199.0     ([27805.0], [3])     9924.658581485359
5   1232072.654  1232669.377 ([15938.657], [1])   353082.313052638
```

I want my mode to be a simple int value.
How can I do it?

Comment: How did your data *get* like this in the first place.  These problems are much easier to solve upstream

Comment: There are two numbers for each mode, so which one do you want?

Comment: @user3483203 I just used numpy and scipy to calculate all my statistical values of data and used pd.Dataframe to construct it.

Comment: @timgeb want only the mode value and not how many times it has appeared. Also I want to get rid of all the brackets.

Comment: @OmkarJagtap ok, but which value is the mode? For example, in the first column, is it `70850.0` or `3`?

Comment: @timgeb I want 70850.0